# Would experimenting with MASM32 break my computer?

Tags: assembly, masm32

Is it safe to play a little bit with it on my computer? I have this hunch that I'm gonna make a terrible mistake while writing some experimental code. Is my fear baseless?

---

**Edit**

Thanks for the quick responses and clarifying my concern. I guess I don't have to worry too much about it. If I'd want to do some dangerous experiments, I'll prepare an virtual machine environment. Thanks again!

Comment: I can write `FORMAT C:` in lots of languages, but writing it in MASM is one of the hardest

Comment: If you're that worried, see if you can get a cheap 2nd-hand junker to experiment on first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to try quite hard to do permanent damage with an assembly language program; I'd guess it's easier to do damage in high-level languages than low-level ones.

If you make a mistake, the worst that will happen is that Windows kills your process or kicks you into the debugger.

Comment: Hmmm.  I think you are being a bit too optimistic about the worst case scenario.  If you are doing something fancy enough, you might manage to accidentally blue screen windows.  Still only temporary, but you could lose all your current work.  The likelihood of doing this by mistake is different depending on the version of windows.

Comment: @Brian: if a user-space process in asm crashes, the OS will kill it, period. You have to start writing kernel-space code to BSOD (unless you're talking pre-win2000).

Comment: @Bahbar: I've seen plenty of cases where debugger applications managed to blue screen Vista because they were trying to register message handlers to broken hwnd handles or whatever.  It's very easy to write a vb6 program that will blue screen Vista if run in the debugger.  I imagine a program designed for a similar task (intercepting messages or whatever) might have similar issues.

Comment: @Brian how so? I can imagine how to make the system unresponsive (`for (;;) ;`), but in the absence of driver/OS bugs, a user process should be able to blue-screen the PC.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: Well, the way my program did it was by calling `SetWindowLong` using `GWL_WNDPROC` to set a new address to the window procedure.  For some reason doing this to a window while running the debugger is a bad idea.  How this translates to a blue screen I have no clue, but the fact that I managed to produce vb6 code which causes blue screens has left me feeling suspicious of people who make any claims about what can and cannot cause blue screens.

Comment: @Brian: Did you root-cause any of those, get to the bottom if it ? I've root-caused my share of BSOD. They _are_ coming from kernel code (usually 3rd party drivers). The other recurring case is faulty hardware.

Comment: @Bahbar: The fact that the root-cause is kernel code does not imply that an assembly program won't inadvertently cause a blue screen (i.e. by also hitting kernel code).

Comment: @Brian: I see your point; it's not specific to asm. Pushing it to its max, wiggling the mouse could BSOD :p

Answer (score 5):

Only if you are very good and you know what you're doing ( sorry for oxymoron :) ).

Also, it was much easier to do in real mode than in protected.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know enough about MASM32 to say whether or not your concerns are justified, but if you're really concerned, and have the means to do so, then why not run MASM32 on an instance of Windows running in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

"Is my fear baseless? "

Not entirely, but probably the worst you would do is wipe your hard disk. And you'd have to a bit of work to do that

Answer (score 2):

About the worst i've ever had happen was my computer froze and I had to restart it. I think you're probably fine.